# What fraction is $\frac{2}{5}$ of $\frac{3}{4}$?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

$\frac{2}{5}$ of blood donors at a centre have group **O** blood. $\frac{3}{4}$ of these donors are under 30. What fraction of the group **O** blood donors at the centre are under 30?

What I did was divide $\frac{2}{5}$ by $\frac{3}{4}$ to get $\frac{8}{15}$. Am I heading in right direction or completely off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: As @TonyK pointed out, this answer is incorrect. See @TonyK's answer for why that is. I'll leave my own response here for reference.**

---

You need the fraction of people who
$$
  \Big(\text{have group O blood}\Big) \mathbf{AND} \Big(\text{are under 30}\Big)
$$

This "**AND**" translates to multiplication, so the fraction of the group O blood donors at the centre that are under 30 would be

$$
  \Big(\text{fraction that have group O blood}\Big) 
  \times 
  \Big(\text{fraction that are under 30}\Big)
$$
}

Comment: AND just means multiply if you are considering possibilties. If you have 3 sorts of ice cream (white, yellow and orange), AND on each sort of each cream you can have 3 sorts of sauces (chocolate, strawberry and tropical), you have in total 3 times 3 = 9 possibilties. It works just the same with the example above.

Comment: It isn't emphasized enough in school that this is what multiplication of fractions is *for*.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a trick question. Assuming that age and blood group are not correlated, the fraction of group **O** blood donors that are under 30 is the same as the fraction of all blood donors that are under 30: $3/4$.

Comment: The way Lee worded the question might be different from what he was given. But of course here we have to go off what Lee actually wrote, which includes the words "*of these* donors" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Robert: It doesn't matter whether "these donors" refers to all the blood donors at the centre, or just those with blood group O. In the first case, my answer is correct; in the second case, the question answer itself!